# Make enumerate have beamer themes when using enumitem

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate, itemize, enumitem

I really like the `enumitem` package, but it seems to have compatibility issues with `beamer`. I could get them to work together for `itemize` lists by using the following:

```
\setitemize{label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
```

It seems to make `itemize` lists follow the current `beamer` theme. But I can't seem to do the same thing for `enumerate`. In particular, when I do this

```
\setenumerate[1]{label=\usebeamerfont*{enumerate item}}
```

I get the error "Use of `\enumerate` doesn't match its definition."

Is it possible to do a similar thing with `enumerate` to make it follow the current `beamer` theme?

Comment: Enumitem beamer compatibility should be a feature request.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be fixed by protecting the beamer use-commands. This is compilable and uses the color of the Singapore beamer theme:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{%
  label=\protect\usebeamerfont{enumerate item}%
        \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate item}%
        \insertenumlabel.}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works!! For some themes where the bullets have backgrounds, do you know how to get that working too?

Comment: @JackCheng depends on the theme, perhaps post a new question with a minimal working example.

Comment: I am using the Frankfurt theme, where the bullets have the gradient circles as background (e.g., just change Singapore to Frankfurt in your example.) This seems closely related to the original question, should I just add it as an edit?

Comment: @JackCheng It's related, but more specific and I guess a bit harder. This question was about fixing the error. Now it's like "how to the (Frankfurt) ball enumerate style into an enumitem label" I guess by including `\usebeamertemplate{enumerate item}`.