# Use ball items in enumerate list with enumitem package

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate, enumitem

In Beamer, I would like to be able to use ball `items` (with a number inside) in an `enumerate` list whose layout is defined by the package `enumitem`.

This question is closely related to [Make enumerate have beamer themes when using enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45921/make-enumerate-have-beamer-themes-when-using-enumitem). Actually a hint is given but does not work.

Hereafter, my MWE.
If you remove `\protect\usebeamertemplate{enumerate item}`, the MWE works.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[ball]
\setenumerate[1]{%
  label=\protect\usebeamerfont{enumerate item}
        \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate item}
        \protect\usebeamertemplate{enumerate item}
        \insertenumlabel.}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Would you have any suggestions to include properly the `item` template? Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Trouble combining `enumitem` and `beamer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31505/5764)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest *not* to use `enumitem` with `beamer`, since this combination  could produce more damages than benefits. Take for example the code given in the answer you linked to in your question:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{%
  label=\protect\usebeamerfont{enumerate item}%
        \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate item}%
        \insertenumlabel.}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This code works and apparently everything it's OK, but something this code "hides" is that now `enumerate` is *not* overlay-aware and this is a serious drawback; adding the typical overlay specification

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{%
  label=\protect\usebeamerfont{enumerate item}%
        \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate item}%
        \insertenumlabel.}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
    \item First item
    \item Second item
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

you get the error message

```
! Package enumitem Error: <+-> undefined.

See the enumitem package documentation for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    

l.14 \end{frame}
```

If you want to customize the list-like environments, you can do it by redefining the corresponding elements as they are defined in `beamer`. For example, the definitions for the `enumerate item` template for each one of the predefined options (`default`, `ball`, `circle`, `square`) can be found in the file `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`. You can then change this definitions according to your needs; a little example, increasing the size of the circle and adding a final dot after the label of the enumeration:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}
{
  \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
    {\pgftransformscale{2}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
    {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}
      \pgftext{\usebeamerfont*{item projected}\insertenumlabel.}}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo. I modified my file beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty as you mentioned and the results are as expected.

Comment: @RolPasto it's not a good idea to modify LaTeX files directly; you can save a copy and edit the copy or do the changes in your document.

Comment: bigshpere goes away when used with `\begin{enumerate}[i]'