# Modifying enumerate items in beamer - insert graphics while generating labels

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate

I'm trying to make myself a beamer template with modified bullets for enumerate and itemize. I have a pdf image of the bullet point that I would like to use. I already have a working solution for itemize, but using the same approach

```
\newcommand{\bpebble}[0]{\includegraphics[height=1.3 ex]{./k_bluepebble.pdf}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}{\bpebble}
```

the numbering vanishes making the enumerate and itemize environments essentially indistinguishable. I've seen a near-satisfactory solution [Use ball items in enumerate list with enumitem package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60592/use-ball-items-in-enumerate-list-with-enumitem-package/60600#60600?newreg=7a4b1bb48ec04aafb84668cdc2dcacbd) in that it modifies the item in front of each enumerate list entry and superimposes a number on top of it, however this uses pgfplots and not an inserted pdf figure.

So, I'm seeking a way to include a pdf graphic into the list bullets and lay a number on top of it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Does `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}{\bpebble\hspace*{-1ex}\theenumi}` work?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it does, with a minor beauty spot. The lower edge of the pebble inserted by command \bpebble is on the same level than the base of the number inserted by \theenumi. Hence, the number is not in the middle of the pebble but a bit too low relative to it. Aside from that (and choosing an appropriate value for the parameter of \hspace) everything works and I think your proposed solution is a very good starting point. Danke.

Comment: Move the number a bit up: `\raisebox{1pt}{\theenumi}`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one possibility allowing you to insert an image as background for the counters in `enumerate` environments; the code illustrates the simple procedure up to level three of nesting (the maximum nesting level for `beamer`). The main command is `\bpebble` with three mandatory arguments:

```
\bpebble{<optionf for \includegraphics>}{<image file>}{<counter to be used over the image>}
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\bpebble[3]{%
  \tikz{
  \node[inner sep=0pt] 
    (image) {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};%
  \node[inner sep=0pt] 
    at (image.center) {#3};%
  }
}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\bpebble{height=2ex}{papiro}{\insertenumlabel}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\bpebble{height=1.8ex}{bricks}{\insertsubenumlabel}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subsubitem}{\bpebble{height=1.6ex}{scroll}{\insertsubsubenumlabel}}

\setbeamercolor*{enumerate item}{fg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{enumerate subitem}{fg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=black} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First.
\item Second.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item First.
    \item Second.
    \end{enumerate}
  \item Third.
  \end{enumerate}
\item Third.
\item Fourth.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]