# Change enumerate label alignment in Beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate, labels

I would like to add enumerated lists to a Beamer presentation.
Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\Alph{enumii}}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First level item
\begin{enumerate}
\item Second level item 1
\item Second level item 2
\item Second level item 3
\item Second level item 4
\item Second level item 5
\item Second level item 6
\item Second level item 7
\item Second level item 8
\item Second level item 9
\item Second level item 10
\item Second level item 11
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you look at the pdf output you can see that the alignment of the alphabetical labels A, B, C etc. looks ugly. Especially the D below C, and I and J between H and K. Here is an image of the output:

[image: beamer-enumerate-list-example]

I would like the to center the labels horizontally (within `\labelwidth`). That is, the horizontal centers of the letters would be placed on a vertical line. How can I do it in Beamer?

I would like to avoid `enumitem` package as it does not work well with Beamer. Previously I had errors with `enumitem` in Beamer similar to those reported here:

[Dealing with long description environment items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52274/dealing-with-long-description-environment-items)

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]. errors

Answer (score 1):

You could define `\makelabelcenter` as follows (the standard `beamer` version of `\makelabel` within an `enumerate` but with `\clap` instead of `\llap` and with an extra `\hss` after the label), and then `\let` `\makelabel` to `\makelabelcenter` at the start of the desired enumeration. Applying this automatically to every second level list/enumeration is harder.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\Alph{enumii}}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\normalsize}

\providecommand\clap[1]{\hbox to0pt{\hss#1\hss}}
\def\makelabelcenter#1{{\hss\clap{{%
        \usebeamerfont*{enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix item}#1}}\hss}}%


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{enumerate}
\item First level item 1
\begin{enumerate}
\let\makelabel\makelabelcenter
\item Second level item 1
\item Second level item 2
\item Second level item 3
\item Second level item 4
\item Second level item 5
\item Second level item 6
\item Second level item 7
\item Second level item 8
\item Second level item 9
\item Second level item 10
\item Second level item 11
\item[Test] Larger label
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Illustration of output]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problem, try to use a monospace font (typewriter font):

(1) Use the `\setbeamerfont` before `\begin{document}`:

```
\setbeamerfont{enumerate subitem}{family=\ttfamily}  % Typewriter Family
```

[image: Enumerate 01]

---

(2) If you need to change the default typewriter font, use this:

```
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono} % Bera Mono type
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setbeamerfont{enumerate subitem}{family=\ttfamily}
```

The Typewriter Fonts Catalogue: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html

[image: Enumerate 02]

Answer (score 0):

Poor man's solution - put every item label in a centered box:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\Alph{enumii}}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First level item
\begin{enumerate}
\item[{\makebox[0.3cm][c]{A}}] Second level item 1 
\item[{\makebox[0.3cm][c]{B}}] Second level item 2
\item[{\makebox[0.3cm][c]{C}}] Second level item 3
\item[{\makebox[0.3cm][c]{D}}] Second level item 4
\item[{\makebox[0.3cm][c]{E}}] Second level item 5
\item[{\makebox[0.3cm][c]{F}}] Second level item 6
\item[{\makebox[0.3cm][c]{G}}] Second level item 7
\item[{\makebox[0.3cm][c]{H}}] Second level item 8
\item[{\makebox[0.3cm][c]{I}}] Second level item 9
\item[{\makebox[0.3cm][c]{J}}] Second level item 10
\item[{\makebox[0.3cm][c]{K}}] Second level item 11
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `enumitem` package to redefine the label using `\makebox`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{%
label=\protect\usebeamerfont{enumerate item}%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate item}%
    \insertenumlabel.%
}%http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45950

\setlist[enumerate,2]{%
label={\protect\usebeamerfont{enumerate item}%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate item}%
    \makebox[\labelwidth][c]{\Alph*}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First level item
\begin{enumerate}
\item Second level item 1
\item Second level item 2
\item Second level item 3
\item Second level item 4
\item Second level item 5
\item Second level item 6
\item Second level item 7
\item Second level item 8
\item Second level item 9
\item Second level item 10
\item Second level item 11
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```