# enumitem breaks beamer's itemize despite fixes

Tags: beamer, enumitem

I thought I had tamed `enumitem`. I had this [itemize fix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24491) and this [enumerate fix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45950).

Then I tried a `[<+->]` construct. It failed. Commmenting the `enumitem` section prevents errors but I'd rather not have to do this.

On its current state, this code produces two errors, one because of the `[<+->]` and another because of the `\onslide`.

```
 \documentclass{beamer}

 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \setitemize{label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
   \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}
   \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24491
 \setenumerate[1]{%
   label=\protect\usebeamerfont{enumerate item}%
         \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate item}%
         \insertenumlabel.}%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45950

 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \begin{itemize}[<+->]
 \item 1
 \item 2
 \end{itemize}
 \onslide<2>{text}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: What do you need the `enumitem` package for, that cannot be done with beamer alone?

Comment: @samcarter I added it to change `itemize`'s items conveniently. Not sure if I'm using it in the future but I'd like to have the option to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is easy: Don't use `enumitem` with beamer.

Beamer has its own mechanism to change the appearance of the itemize item and it's very flexible -- so no need to use another package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\includegraphics[width=2em]{duck}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item 1
            \item 2
        \end{itemize}
        \onslide<2>{text}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It does seem that not using `enumitem` is the beter choice.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` as a workaround (see [beamer documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) page 89).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{%
    label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}%
        \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}%
}%http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24491
\setlist[enumerate,1]{%
    label=\protect\usebeamerfont{enumerate item}%
        \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate item}%
        \insertenumlabel.%
}%http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45950

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 1
        \item 2
    \end{itemize}
    \onslide<2>{text}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

**Just for fun:** You could also define a new key for enumitem to specify the default overlay specification. I, however, would rather recommend using `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification` directly as shown above.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{%
    label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}%
        \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}%
}%http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24491
\setlist[enumerate,1]{%
    label=\protect\usebeamerfont{enumerate item}%
        \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate item}%
        \insertenumlabel.%
}%http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45950

% definition of new key for enumitem:
\makeatletter
\enitkv@key{enumitem}{overlay}{%
    \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[overlay=<+->]
        \item 1
        \item 2
    \end{itemize}
    \onslide<2>{text}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Why I would recommend using the first approach:**
The second approach has no advantage because it is internally using the first.
The first approach uses standard commands which -- if a reader does not know them already -- can easily look them up in the documentation.
The second approach on the other hand may confuse other people reading your code because they will most likely assume the key to be defined by the enumitem package and when they try it in their own code will be frustrated that it does not work. And *you* need to remember that you need to define this key for every single document where you want to use it (and possibly need to look up the definition every single time).

The first is faster to type because the autocompletion will do it for you. Using the autocompletion also ensures that you do not make typing mistakes.

The layout should be consistent. Therefore you should use `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification` once in your preamble and then you will probably not need it again.

---

**Edit:** I have replaced `\setitemize` and `\setenumerate` by `\setlist` because according to footnote 7 on page 9 in the [enumitem documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) those are deprecated.

Comment: oh you just did exactly what I was posting:-) I'll delete mine!

Comment: I'm leaning more towards the second option since I won't always use `[<+->]`. What makes you prefer the first option?

I copied the `enumerate` block and placed the `1` with a `2` to be able to use nested `enumerate`s. Is this the recommended thing to do?

Comment: @Kurzd I have added my reasons for why I prefer the first option to my anwer. If you are sure that you want `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` just for a single itemize you can use it locally inside of that itemize. Without knowing your specific use case, however, I would in general recommend using it globally because I think it is easier to follow a presentation if the slides build up matching to how one is talking.

Comment: @Kurzd If you want to apply options to *all* levels you can leave out the number: `\setlist[enumerate]`. If you want to apply options to *some* levels you can list them, seperated by commas: `\setlist[enumerate,1,2]`. (see enumitem documentation page 9)