# Item is misplaced using overlay and `Copenhagen` theme

Tags: beamer, positioning, enumerate, itemize, themes

Please consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{}
        Text
        \begin{onlyenv}<1-2>
            \begin{enumerate}
                \setcounter{enumi}{1}
                \item Text
                \begin{columns}[T]
                    \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
                        \begin{itemize}
                            \item $n=0$
                        \end{itemize}
                    \end{column}
                    \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
                        \begin{itemize}
                            \item $n=1$
                        \end{itemize}
                    \end{column}
                \end{columns}
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{onlyenv}
        
        \begin{onlyenv}<3-4>
            \begin{enumerate}
                \setcounter{enumi}{2}
                \item PROBLEM WITH THIS ENUMERATE LABEL
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Text here
                    \item More text here
                \end{itemize}
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{onlyenv}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

As you can see, the third item is misplaced (the same happens with `itemize` environment).

I tried several things, but one thing came to my mind: What happens if we delete `\usetheme{Copenhagen}`? The item is well placed.

However I need that theme, and also the `enumerate` environments have to be separated in order to use `onlyenv`.

Perhaps adding `\usepackage{enumitem}` and moving that item to the right? I came across this excellent answer: ["Don't use `enumitem` with beamer."](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356961/152550)

How can we solve this issue using the theme and preserving overlays?

Comment: Strange.  The wrong indentation is trigged by the `itemize`(s) in the `columns` in the first overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the problem by placing your columns after the `itemize` environment instead of at the end of it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{}
        Text
        \begin{onlyenv}<1-2>
            \begin{enumerate}
                \setcounter{enumi}{1}
                \item Text
            \end{enumerate}
            \begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
                \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item $n=0$
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{column}
                \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item $n=1$
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{column}
            \end{columns}
        \end{onlyenv}
        
        \begin{onlyenv}<3-4>
            \begin{enumerate}
                \setcounter{enumi}{2}
                \item PROBLEM WITH THIS ENUMERATE LABEL
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Text here
                    \item More text here
                \end{itemize}
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{onlyenv}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Sam!! Glad to see you again. `:)`

Comment: @manooooh You're welcome!